# How to find a word in a text file and edit and delete next lines and words

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, text-files

I want to find a word in a text file using a batch file and then I want to remove that line containing the word and also delete some other lines below for example:

```
# Materials file generated by ZModeler 2.2.6 (Build 992).

newmtl Black__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.15 0.15 0.15
illum 1

newmtl Carbon__CarPaint_
Ka 0.69 0.69 0.69
Kd 0.69 0.69 0.69
Ks 0.60 0.60 0.60
illum 1
map_Kd carbon.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Chrome__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 1.00 1.00 1.00
illum 1
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Details_Int__Default_A_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.30 0.30 0.30
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int.dds
bump apollo_2008_details_int_ts.dds

newmtl Details_Int2__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.40 0.40 0.40
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int2.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl C1_Lea__Default_N_
Ka 0.95 0.46 0.07
Kd 0.95 0.46 0.07
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 1
map_Kd moket2.dds
bump ts_leather3.dds

newmtl MAT_1__CarPaint_
Ka 0.69 0.69 0.69
Kd 0.69 0.69 0.69
Ks 0.60 0.60 0.60
illum 1
map_Kd carbon.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Moquette__Default_
Ka 0.36 0.36 0.36
Kd 0.36 0.36 0.36
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1
map_Kd moquette1.dds

newmtl Paint__CarPaint2_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 1.00 1.00 1.00
illum 2
Ns 100.000000
bump fio_damage_2.dds
refl cubemap.dds
map_Kd user_tex.dds
map_Kd impact_maps.dds

newmtl Red__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1

newmtl Screen__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Plastic__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1

newmtl Alcantara__CarVelour_
Ka 0.37 0.37 0.37
Kd 0.37 0.37 0.37
Ks 1.00 1.00 1.00
illum 2
Ns 100.000000
map_Kd moket2.dds
bump ts_moket2.dds
map_Ks moket2.dds

newmtl Details_Int_Alp__Default_A___GLT_
Ka 0.21 0.21 0.21
Kd 0.21 0.21 0.21
Ks 0.80 0.80 0.80
illum 2
Ns 80.000000
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int.dds
bump apollo_2008_details_int_ts.dds
map_Ks apollo_2008_details_int.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Details_Int_Alp__Default_A___GLT_
Ka 0.23 0.23 0.23
Kd 0.23 0.23 0.23
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int.dds
bump apollo_2008_details_int_ts.dds
map_Ks apollo_2008_details_int.dds

newmtl Details_Int2_Al__CarPaint_
Ka 0.95 0.95 0.95
Kd 0.95 0.95 0.95
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int2.dds

newmtl HUD__DashBoard_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.30 0.30 0.30
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl Patch__Default_A_
Ka 0.44 0.44 0.44
Kd 0.44 0.44 0.44
Ks 0.00 0.00 0.00
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int2.dds
bump apollo_2008_details_int2_ts.dds

newmtl A_C2_C__Default_A___GLT_
Ka 0.89 0.53 0.15
Kd 0.89 0.53 0.15
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
map_Kd couture.dds
bump ts_couture.dds
map_Ks couture.dds

newmtl Leather__Default_N_
Ka 0.36 0.36 0.36
Kd 0.36 0.36 0.36
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 1
map_Kd moket2.dds
bump ts_leather3.dds

newmtl HUD_01__DashBoard_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.30 0.30 0.30
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int.dds
refl cubeint.dds

newmtl C3_L__Default_N_
Ka 1.00 0.60 0.00
Kd 1.00 0.60 0.00
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 1
map_Kd moket2.dds
bump ts_leather3.dds

newmtl A_C1_P__Default_A_
Ka 1.00 0.51 0.18
Kd 1.00 0.51 0.18
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 1
map_Kd apollo_2008_details_int2.dds
bump apollo_2008_details_int2_ts.dds

newmtl Belt__Default_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
map_Kd seatbelt.dds
map_Ks seatbelt.dds

newmtl Grip__Default_N_
Ka 0.35 0.35 0.35
Kd 0.35 0.35 0.35
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
map_Ks dot2.dds
bump ts_dot2.dds

newmtl Plastic2__CarPaint_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1

newmtl A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_
Ka 0.89 0.53 0.15
Kd 0.89 0.53 0.15
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
map_Kd couture_croix.dds
bump couture_croix_ts.dds
map_Ks couture_croix.dds

newmtl C3_Pla__Default_
Ka 0.29 0.29 0.29
Kd 0.29 0.29 0.29
Ks 0.20 0.20 0.20
illum 1

newmtl Glass_I__CarGlassDirt_
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0.00 0.00 0.00
illum 4
map_Kd apollo_2008_glass_i.dds
```

As you can see each phrase has the same format as the others

```
newmtl A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_  :The material name
Ka 0.89 0.53 0.15   :Some of the numbers for transparency reflection and ...
Kd 0.89 0.53 0.15   :Some of the numbers for transparency reflection and ...
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10   :Some of the numbers for transparency reflection and ...
illum 2             :One illum
Ns 10.000000        :Some of the numbers for transparency reflection and ...
map_Kd couture_croix.dds :Texture names
bump couture_croix_ts.dds :Texture names
map_Ks couture_croix.dds  :Texture names
```

Okay so for example I want to find newmtl A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_ or a part of the material name then I want to tell it to change the illum 2 to illum 4, 3 lines under material name is illum here but maybe it changes so I want to tell it first find material name then find the first illum then delete the line and write illum 4 instead.

I'm working on a code yet but I couldn't get anything in one day I'll post a code till here tnx for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to name this Batch file **change.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~4" neq "" goto begin
echo Usage: %0 item=value IN materialName
echo/
echo For example:
echo    %0 illum=4 IN A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_
goto :EOF

:begin

set "var=%~1"
set "value=%~2"

rem Get the number of the line that contain the materialName (the first instance only)
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%~4" input.txt') do set "lines=%%a" & goto continue
:continue

rem Open a code block to read from input.txt and write to output.txt
< input.txt (

   rem Read and write the first "lines" lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
      set "line="
      set /P "line="
      echo(!line!
   )

   rem Search for the desired variable and change its value
   call :changeVar

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > output.txt

rem Replace the original file by the new one
move /Y output.txt input.txt >NUL
goto :EOF


:changeVar
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   for /F %%a in ("%line%") do (
      if "%%a" equ "%var%" (
         echo %%a %value%
         goto endChange
      )
   )
   echo(%line%
goto changeVar
:endChange
exit /B
```

**EDIT**: *Usage example added*

```
C:\> copy input.txt inputOrig.txt
        1 archivo(s) copiado(s).

C:\> change
Usage: change item=value IN materialName

For example:
   change illum=4 IN A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_

C:\> change illum=4 IN A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_

C:\> fc inputOrig.txt input.txt
Comparando archivos inputOrig.txt y INPUT.TXT
***** inputOrig.txt
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 2
Ns 10.000000
***** INPUT.TXT
Ks 0.10 0.10 0.10
illum 4
Ns 10.000000
*****


C:\>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I couldn't use it can you explain a bit how to use it? tnx you're really awesome at this. :)

Comment: Thank you it works with illums now :) but it doesn't work with 
Kd 0.29 0.29 0.29
you can just change Kd 0.29 to whatever but I couldn't change the next two 0.29 and 0.29 numbers.

Comment: Just enclose the whole value in quotes: `change Kd="0.29 0.29 0.29" IN A_C2_CC__Default_A___GLT_`.